# log4J serial log number

Tags: java, log4j

There is any option to use `log4j` with format the log number

```
1| INFO | 2017-07-12 09:17:37 | MainApplication.java | 28 | hello world
2| INFO | 2017-07-12 09:17:37 | MainApplication.java | 28 | hello world
SERIAL Num. | INFO | 2017-07-12 09:17:37 | MainApplication.java | 28 | hello world
```

My format for now is like that

```
%5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %-20.30F | %L | %m%n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `%sn` to print the event sequenceNumber in `log4j2`.

> Includes a sequence number that will be incremented in every event.
>   The counter is a static variable so will only be unique within
>   applications that share the same converter Class object.

But there is no similar configs in `log4j 1.x`